# We all know about linear algebra; but does a 'quadratic algebra' exist as well?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, quadratics

I know this question sounds completely idiotic, but I swear its title is exactly what I want to know.

Linear algebra focuses on inherently linear phenomena, characterized by several variables that show up with a power of at most one. Mathematically speaking, vector spaces were created to abstract this concept in a very elegant way, since their elements can be added together and multiplied by a scalar, but they can't be multiplied together.

But just like linear approximation can be useful, sometimes quadratic approximation can be just as useful and maybe even better. So **does there exist an algebraic structure that takes vector spaces one step further** and allows you to study combinations like $\alpha\mathbf{a}^2 + \beta\mathbf{b}$, but not $\alpha\mathbf{a}^3 + \beta\mathbf{b}$, just like vector spaces allow you to investigate theorems and truths about expressions of the form $\alpha\mathbf{a} + \beta\mathbf{b}$, but not $\alpha\mathbf{a}^2 + \beta\mathbf{b}$?

Comment: There are quadratic forms (which we also study in linear algebra).

Comment: What is your definition of the product of two vectors?

Comment: One of the issues is that the composition of two linear functions is linear, but the composition of two quadratic functions is typically not quadratic. (Even over familiar structures.) So you lose one of the most useful tools.